# Is this Proof on Manifold Correct?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

**I want to prove this**

Prove that the set of vectors $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ with pairwise distinct coordinates is a manifold. Hence, find its dimension.

**Attempt**

Let $M$ be the set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with pairwise distinct coordinates. We know $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a manifold, and $M\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. All we have to do is prove that $M$ is an open set (since an open subset of a manifold is a manifold).

To prove that $M$ is an open set, for any $x=(x_1,…,x_n)\in M$, consider $B_\epsilon (x) = \{(y_1,…,y_n)|\sqrt{(y_1-x_1)^2 +…+ (y_n-x_n)^2} <\epsilon  \}$, where $\epsilon >0$. We can choose $\epsilon$ so small that the coordinates of any vector in this ball will be sufficiently close to the corresponding coordinates of $x$. Therefore, no two distinct coordinates can be equal. So, $B_\epsilon (x)$ is entirely contained in $M$. Hence, $M$ is open. And its dimension is n.

**Question**

I feel my prove of $M$ being an open set is weak. Is there something I am getting wrong here? Is there a way I can improve on this proof?

Again, is $n$ the dimension of $M$?

Your help would be really appreciated.

**Note**: I tried to put brace brackets in the definition for the open ball by using “\ {“ and “}\” but the brace brackets didn’t display.

Comment: it is fine. if you wanted to "improve" it somehow, you could find an explicit $\epsilon$ that works

Comment: @Timkinsella my concern is the claim I made that we could make $\epsilon$ so small that the coordinates of any vector in the ball will be sufficiently close to the corresponding coordinates of $x$. I know that is what I want, and that is why I wrote that but I am not totally convinced myself. If the ball is in $M$ and $M\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, then there would be some points of $\mathbb{R}^n$ in the ball that are the same as a given point in the ball. This is what I have been thinking, but I am not sure. I think I am mixing things up here.

Comment: I think you are mixing things up. You need to choose an  so that no points in the ball have any coordinates which are equal to each other. One way to do this is to look at the minimum pairwise distance between any two coordinates in your original point and let  be half that. Then you need to argue using the triangle inequality that no points in the ball have a pair of equal coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea is absolutely correct. Your strategy is to prove that $M$ is open in $\mathbb R^n$ which implies that $M$ is an $n$-dimensional manifold. However, it should be elaborated a bit more precisely.

Let $x \in M$. Define
$$r = \min \{ \lvert x_i - x_j \rvert \mid i,j \in \{1,\ldots,n \} \text{ with } i \ne j \} .$$
This is a positive number. We claim that $B_{r/2}(x) \subset M$.

So let $y \in B_{r/2}(x)$ which means $\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - x_i)^
2} < r/2$. Hence all $\lvert y_i - x_i \rvert = \sqrt{(y_i - x_i)^
2} < r/2$. Assume that $y_i = y_j$ for some $i,j \in \{1,\ldots,n \}$ with  $i \ne j$. Then
$$\lvert x_i - x_j \rvert =  \lvert (x_i - y_i) + (y_i - y_j) + (y_j - x_j) \rvert = \lvert (x_i - y_i) +  (y_j - x_j) \rvert \le \lvert x_i - y_i \rvert + \lvert y_j - x_j \rvert \\ < r/2 + r/2 = r$$
which is a contradiction.